# How to check if a particular word is surrounded by space within a string

Tags: php, regex

For example ,

```
$string ="John and his sister are in europe";
```

I would like to see if the word and is both preceded and followed by space , so I can replace it by & . How can I quickly do this in PHP ?

Comment: Why do you feel you need regex for this?  Have you made any attempt to do this yourself?

Comment: Did you try to search for 'php replace space after word' :/

Comment: by "replace it" do you mean to replace the word or the space?

Comment: Yes I tried .. please dont be too rude , I am asking because I obviously need help

Comment: http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html

Comment: What about punctuation. In the sentence `John and his sister, they are in europe` would you consider the comma part of the word? Would "sister" be replaced? And would you replace the spaces too?

Comment: I just want to replace and with & if it is preceded and surrounded by space ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use str_replace?

```
str_replace(" and ", " & ", $string)
```

Answer (score 1):

The regex would be `/ (.*?) /`, using `?` to make it a lazy capture instead of a greedy one.

[This](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html) is a great place to learn regex, and [this](http://regex.alf.nu/) is a great place to practice it in real time (seeing exactly what's matched as you type it)